# Can we use filter in django templates?

Tags: python, django

I was curious to know can we use filter tag in Django templates like that we have in views.

like we have in views:-

```
studentcount = Users.objects.using('cms').filter(universityId=item.id,userTypeId=2).count()
```

can we use something like that in templates:-

```
<td>{{ item.users.userTypeId=1_set.all.count }}</td>
```

i know above method is wrong and not working just wrote it so that it is better to understand.And my user model is there in case you want to see my user model.

I have a users table which has 3 types of users Student, Faculty and Club.

My user model:-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cms.models.masterUserTypes import MasterUserTypes
from cms.models.universities import Universities
from cms.models.departments import MasterDepartments



# WE ARE AT MODELS/APPUSERS

requestChoice = (
    ('male', 'male'),
    ('female', 'female'),
    )


class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    userTypeId = models.ForeignKey(MasterUserTypes, db_column="userTypeId")
    universityId = models.ForeignKey(Universities, db_column="universityId")  
    departmentId = models.ForeignKey(MasterDepartments , db_column="departmentId",help_text="")  
    name = models.CharField(db_column="name",max_length=255,help_text="")
    username = models.CharField(db_column="username",unique=True, max_length=255,help_text="")
    email = models.CharField(db_column="email",unique=True, max_length=255,help_text="")
    password = models.CharField(db_column="password",max_length=255,help_text="")
    bio = models.TextField(db_column="bio",max_length=500,help_text="")
    gender = models.CharField(db_column="gender",max_length=6, choices=requestChoice,help_text="")
   class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
```

Comment: why do you want to do it in a template rather than doing it inside the view and contexting it to the template?

Comment: see I am fetching total count of users and its subtypes like total student, total faculty and total club and that process of data fetching was very slow so i am using lazy loading to fetch the data with server side pagination..so I want to use filter in Django's templates....if it is posible otherwise i have to make my custum template tags